# Thread access to stack of another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Am I right in thinking it is OK for a thread to access a variable that exists in the stack of another thread?

This is assuming the function in which the stack variable was instantiated has not yet returned.

I think I read somewhere that threads should only share heap memory but I'm now questioning whether that is correct?

This is using POSIX pthreads in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's an implementation-defined behaviour whether you are allowed to access the stack variable (variable with automatic storage duration) of another thread from a C11 perspective which provides thread support (but the interfaces are different to POSIX threads), assuming that stack variable is still alive (e.g., you pass an address of a local variable from main function to another thread created via [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) and the main returns exits by calling [`pthread_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html).Thus the variable passed to the thread is gone and it would be [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is no different to using pointer to local variables from other function after that function has returned - threads or not).

But in practice, this is likely to work on most (all?) POSIX thread implementations. I am not aware of any POSIX implementation where this isn't supported.

---

Looking at the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_404), it actually requires that access to automatic variables be supported:

> A single flow of control within a process. Each thread has its own thread ID, scheduling priority and policy, errno value, floating point environment, thread-specific key/value bindings, and the required system resources to support a flow of control. Anything whose address may be determined by a thread, including but not limited to static variables, storage obtained via malloc(), directly addressable storage obtained through implementation-defined functions, and **automatic variables**, are accessible to all threads in the same process.

(emphasis mine).

So this should be fine on any POSIX implementation.

Comment: but its not implementation defined behaviour whether you are allowed to access the heap. So that could be a reason why if you want to share some variable between threads you do it on the heap?

Comment: my thinking is that main() stack can't be deallocated prior to all threads having done their thing as main() has to cover the lifetime of the parent process? (I haven't explained that very well but hopefully you know what I mean)

Comment: to put it another way, all threads have to be finished anyway at the point when main() returns as that is the end of the process, thus a thread cannot ever attempt to access a deallocated main() stack as it wouldn't exist any more

Comment: Yes (to your 1st comment). The implementation-defined behaviour mainly comes from C standard. But [POSIX actually guarantees](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_233) the access to stack variables: "A single flow of control within a process. Each thread has its [..]. Anything whose address may be determined by a thread, including but not limited to static variables, storage obtained via malloc(), directly addressable storage obtained through implementation-defined functions, and automatic variables, are accessible to all threads in the same process."

Comment: "main() stack can't be deallocated prior to all threads having done" - Not necessarily. Main thread could call `pthread_exit` to exit itself while the *process* is still alive (with other threads). A process dies/exits when the last thread in it dies.

Comment: good point! I'm using posix pthread lib on linux, so that posix guarantee is just the info i was after. I'm thinking a port across platforms to winpthread and you lose that guarantee - so maybe another pragmatic reason to utilise the heap?

Comment: I don't know much about winpthreads. But I'd expect it to work there given they call it "pthreads". So it should be fine on any POSIX implementation.

Comment: You say, "assuming the stack has not been de-allocated," but isn't the real issue whether or not the function call to which the local variable belongs is still active or not? if function `foobar()` hands a pointer to one of its own locals to some other thread, and the other thread uses the pointer after `foobar()` has returned, then I hope the outcome is formally _Undefined Behavior_ even if the thread that called `foobar()` still is running.

Comment: @jameslarge " but isn't the real issue whether or not the function call to which the local variable belongs is still active or not?" That's what I meant by "stack hasn't been de-allocated". But wording could have been better/clearer. I edited to expand the answer a bit.

Comment: thats also what I understood by 'stack hasn't been de-allocated' - the function to which the variable belongs *is* still active. Thats really the heart of my question, i.e. *assuming that* a function is still active, can another thread safely access its stack variables? I'm also interested in what you *should* do on a pragmatic basis, i.e. is it so potentially error-prone you should always default to using the heap (for an easier life)?

Comment: I was pretty clear that attempting to access a stack variable of a function that has returned from another thread was a definite no-no. It doesn't exist any more so its undefined as to what the memory location your trying to look at has in it at that point..

Comment: @bph I know you were clear in your question. I initially only added the "assuming .." bit just for completeness (someone else might read it without the context of the question).

Comment: "is it so potentially error-prone you should always default to using the heap?" - It's no more error-prone than (accidentally) returning a pointer to a local array. More often with threads, the "creator" thread would wait (`pthread_join`) for the created threads to finish. So it's a non-issue. If it doesn't, then you'd know it (and thus use heap). If you are calling `pthread_exit` from a thread, that creates other threads, you'd already be familiar with such use-after-thread-exit cases. It *could* happen (like all programming errors). But it's not bad idiom or particularly error-prone IMO.

Comment: fantastic! thats the icing on the cake in terms of the answer - haha returning a ptr to a local array - I'm sure I've been guilty several times. I've got a much better mental-model of whats going on now with the threading/memory situation - thanks..