# Access an object with automatic storage duration from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, lifetime

I stumbled upon this question: [Thread access to stack of another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794624/thread-access-to-stack-of-another-thread). Linked question is about plain C, but my main language is C++, so I tried to find if the same rules apply to C++.

I found this section in C11 draft `N1570`:

> 6.2.4.5 An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without
>   the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration, as
>   do some compound literals. The result of attempting to indirectly
>   access an object with automatic storage duration from a thread other
>   than the one with which the object is associated is
>   **implementation-defined**.

I believe corresponding section from C++20 draft `N4810` is `[basic.stc.auto]` and it does not mention this case. C++11 draft has exactly the same text as C++20 in this part.

Under `[intro.multithread]` I've found this sentence with footnote:

> Every thread in a program can potentially access every object and function in a program.
>
> An object with automatic or thread storage duration (6.6.5) is
>   associated with one specific thread, and can be accessed by a
>   different thread only indirectly through a pointer or reference
>   (6.7.2).

So I assume in C++ it's always fine to access an object with automatic storage duration from another thread (until the end of an object's lifetime and if there is no data race of course). Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know of any reason why a thread can't pass a pointer or reference to a local variable to another thread; assuming lifetime and data race issues are taken care of, of course. It's done pretty routinely in C++ - see e.g. [an example here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), in particular `std::thread t3(f2, std::ref(n));`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I know. That's why I was so surprised when I learned that it's implementation-defined in plain C.

Comment: For what it’s worth, that text is in the latest C2x draft I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the line you quoted for C++ effectively establishes that all threads in a C++ program see the same address space. One of the cornerstones of the C++ object model is that every living object has a unique address [[intro.object]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#9). Based on [[intro.multithread]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#1), you can pass a pointer or reference to an object created in one thread's automatic or thread-local storage to another thread and access the object from that second thread as long as the object is guaranteed to exist and there are no data races…

Interestingly, the C standard doesn't appear to explicitly give similar guarantees. However, the fact that different objects have different addresses and the address of an object is the same from the perspective of each thread in the program would still seem to be an implicit, necessary consequence of the rules of the language. C18 specifies that the address of a live object doesn't change [6.2.4/2], any object pointer can be compared to a pointer to `void` [6.5.9/2], and two pointers compare equal if and only if they point to the same object [6.5.9/6]. Storage class is not part of the type of a pointer. Thus, a pointer pointing to an object in the automatic storage of one thread must compare unequal to a pointer to some other object in the automatic storage of another thread, as well as to a pointer pointing to some object with different storage duration. And any two pointers pointing to the same object in automatic storage of some thread must compare equal no matter which thread got these pointers from where in what way. Thus, it can't really be that the value of a pointer means something different in different threads. Even if it may be implementation-defined whether a given thread can actually access an object in automatic storage of another thread via a pointer, I can, e.g., make a global `void*`, assign to it a pointer to an object of automatic storage from one thread, and, given the necessary synchronization, have another thread observe this pointer and compare it to some other pointer. The standard guarantees me that the comparison can only be true if I compare it to another pointer that points to the same object, i.e., the same object in automatic storage of the other thread, and that it must be true in this case…

I cannot give you the exact rationale behind the decision to leave it implementation-defined whether one thread can access objects in automatic storage of another thread. But one can imagine a hypothetical platform where, e.g., only the thread a stack was allocated for is given access to the pages of that stack, e.g., for security reasons. I don't know of any actual platform where this would be the case. However, an OS *could* easily do this, even on x86. C is already based on some, arguably, quite strong assumptions concerning the address model. I think it's a good guess that the C standards committee was simply trying to avoid adding any more restrictions on top of that…